# Is time emergent from quantum entanglement?

Tags: time, quantum-entanglement

This paper shows that 2 photons in a toy universe (isolated box) are seen as static to an outside observer unless interacted with/entangled with. It states that it shows that time emerges from entanglement, I don't know much about physics but wouldn't that imply that without entanglement, time wouldn't exist? But time isn't a physical tangible thing so how can it emerge from something?

- E. Moreva, G. Brida, M. Gramegna, V. Giovannetti, L. Maccone, and M. Genovese, "Time from quantum entanglement: An experimental illustration", [*Phys. Rev. A* **89**, 052122 (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.89.052122), [arXiv:1310.4691](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4691).

Comment: How do I read the full paper on there?

Comment: Click the download pdf.

Comment: FYI this idea was introduced by [Page and Wootters in 1983](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.27.2885). Credit where credit's due...

Comment: That's right about the idea, but Moreva & her team designed the experiment that validates it.

Comment: Credit has been given, see reference [9] of Moreva *et al*.

Comment: Time is a perfectly physical thing. Proof: You can measure time. In face there are dynamical equations that determine how time behaves (the Einstein field equations) just like there are dynamical equations that determine how electric fields behave (the Maxwell equations).

Comment: If my 1st comment on my own answer is right, you (or some being identical to yourself--i.e., containing only the same no. of each of the same types of subatomic particle that you contain, in a potentially observable region that, during "your lifetime", would've contained only the same no. of each of the same types of subatomic particle that the region potentially observable to you has contained--will exist, intermittently, during a long future, with the only differences between you and your surroundings and those regions and their contents being differences in scale.  Viva causal separation!

Comment: Re Moreva's experiment cited by the OP, a black hole does look static when seen from the outside by her "external observer":  With at least half of all stars generally considered to be binary, the elliptical orbit still followed by their former partner is the main evidence we've seen of those formed by the gravitational collapse of that partner.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting approach.

To answer your question,

> time isn't a physical tangible thing so how can it emerge from
>   something?

The idea is to think of time in two ways.

In one sense, "time" is the time that is in the equations of physics. That's the t in the equations of the paper, it's the parameter that describes how the states of all systems in the universe change.

However, actual measurements from within the universe cannot measure "t". All they can do is look at the *correlation* between the state of one thing - say, the hands of a clock - and the state of another thing - say, the conditions of a chemical reaction. So when we actually measure time, what we're measuring is these correlations.

The paper investigates a toy model, showing that measurements of such correlations from within the system - within the universe - will reveal that things correlate in this way, so that it will appear to things within it that time passes, that clocks measure time and there are processes and states that change in time. At the same time, the overall state of the system does *not* change in the parametric time t, and if it were possible to make measurements on the whole system from the outside the measurer would see that nothing changes, his measurement results appear all static and the state appears all static.

In this way time "emerges" from the physics: it is the observed time from within the system that emerges, out of how correlations are measured from within.

> wouldn't that imply that without entanglement, time wouldn't exist

Yes, if that model captures the way time emerges in the real world - measured time would not exist (but parametric time would!) without entanglement.

That this is actually true is far from certain, even for the writers. They're just offering it as a motivation to explore that idea.

Comment: When you say measured time would not, but parametric time would exist without entanglement, what do you mean? What's the difference between measured and parametric time?

Comment: Parametric time is the parameter t in the equations, it is what moves every system equally through "(parametric) time". Measured time is the correlation between events as seen from within the universe. It's the fact that we see the clock hand moving 12 hours as the day becomes night, it's the time we actually measure from clocks. In the model WITHOUT entanglement when parametric time moves forward measured time would not.

Comment: So, time would still exist though without entanglement, like planets still move and all, right? Just not the measured time?

Comment: Planets moving are a kind of clock. You can look up in the sky, see that one star (planet) is in a different position from where it was before, and thus deduce that time has passed. Without entanglement, according to the model, measurements from within the universe will reveal no such clocks. Time (including your subjective time, as it's one part of your body measuring another part of you) would stand still.

Comment: So, does it change anything though? Since we have entanglement, whether or not time emerges from it, we still have time?

Comment: The question is whether time, measured time, fundamentally emerges from entanglement. The model attempts to show it might. I don't know whether it does, nor do the writers, but if that's correct - well, I think that's interesting.

Comment: So if this paper is right, what would an external observer to our universe see? How could our universe be static to an external observer?

Comment: Also, is parametric time as you state like coordinate time? And is measured time like proper time?

Comment: I'd say it is.  Take it from the source, sections 21-27 in Einstein's 1916 pop.sci. book on GR, at https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_II#Section_23_-_Behaviour_of_Clocks_and_Measuring-Rods_on_a_Rotating_Body_of_Reference

Comment: "In the model WITHOUT entanglement when parametric time moves forward measured time would not" Isn't this a nice violation of the Principle of correspondence?

Comment: "So if this paper is right, what would an external observer to our universe see? How could our universe be static to an external observer?" I don't claim that I grasp whats going on here, but for the moment i would say that the point is, that an external observer simply is not an observer.

Comment: A (vastly) larger-scaled version of Moreva's experiment, or one resembling it, seems to have just hit the jackpot, as described at https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/video/einsteins-quantum-riddle/  .

Comment: The above experiment used two observatories about 1 mi. apart to receive entangled signals from a source midway between them, thru filters at the observatories that were changed randomly (by radiation from one or the other of 2 quasars, ea. billions of ly away), in a "Bell test" which leaves very little "wiggle room" for the possibility that quantum entanglement is not real:  This is considered to favor the "holographic principle" (that what we perceive as space & time are projections, onto the infinitely-distant inner surface of a sphere, of a reality dependent upon neither of them).

Answer (score 2):

What's being rather plausibly suggested, in Moreva's experiment, is a physical apparition of the time dimension.  In reality (as compared to what Physics Teacher has correctly described as her "toy model"), such an apparition could only occur (at least in the well-accepted model of time as having a thermodynamic basis) in an overall environment either extremely close to thermal equilibrium (as discussed by Aguirre and Carroll at https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0417), or in one or more relatively small regions causally separated from the remainder of that environment's space:  Of those two possibilities, the latter seems much the more probable, given the astronomical evidence for the existence of black holes.

However, although the inflationary cosmological models generally seem to accommodate variations in spatial scale, the only one I've found that implicitly requires such variations is Nikodem J. Poplawski's "cosmology with torsion" (detailed in many papers, written between 2010 and 2020, that are available free on Arvix), which is based on effects of gravitational collapse in the materialization and interactions of known types of subatomic particles, rather than having any basis in any hypothesized field of "inflaton" particles, which may remain extremely unlikely to be observable prior to their hypothetical decay into photons, electrons, etc.

Whereas the other inflationary cosmologies are (AFAIK) all based on General Relativity, the torsion-based one is derived from the more recent "Einstein-Cartan Theory" that was developed by Einstein through conversations with Elie Cartan, and is reportedly more complex mathematically, although its compatibility with the CMB data was reported to be complete in a 2015 analysis by Desai.  Its basic difference is that it requires all fermions to have spatial extent, which was an assumption often incorporated into pop-sci texts prior to the many practical applications of quantum physics, that have resulted in the current wait for a theory of quantum gravity.

I'm bringing these facts to the attention of PSE's participants in the hope that some of those familiar with ECT might have the reputation (1,000) adequate to establish an "Einstein-Cartan" tag, which might facilitate comparisons between cosmologies by prospective students.

Update on this answer:  Although Poplawski 1st described his model (in his 2010 "Cosmology with torsion") as "an alternative to cosmic inflation", it's generally described as a version or adjunct of inflation, with the bounce effects I've described being substituted for action of an inflaton field (which, unlike stars, doesn't rotate).  In response to today's news about a successful and larger-scaled version of Moreva's experiment on "time from quantum entanglement", I'd like to point out the fact that the shape of Poplawski's model of local universes, each of which he describes as resembling a three-dimensional version of the surface of a ball, itself resembles the "two sheet" model of space locally appearing flat, but connected at many points by fermions whose curved surfaces form "bridges" between them, that was described by Einstein and Rosen in their 1935 paper at    https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.48.73  .  To me, it's the intuited association between time and rotating or spinning objects (whether they're electrons or clock dials) that makes his model seem more consistent with the emergence of thermodynamic time than other relativistic models might be:  Thermodynamics is the study of heat over time, and interaction or collisions between spinning objects is what would bring it most completely into the picture.

Comment: Poplawski's cosmology allows a formation that is (per Guth's "The Inflationary Universe") not practicable in models of field-based inflation:  By the addition of mass to its large star, a species faced with the extinction imposed by that star's life cycle might, if that star would've happened to be of a size only marginally inadequate for its collapse into a black hole, have added mass allowing it to collapse into a black hole rather than collapsing into a neutron star, thereby initiating the formation of a local universe eventually containing stars liable to collapse into smaller black holes.

Comment: (I'm posting my previous comment as a "suggestion for improvement", as my own credentials in physics are inadequate to sustain such a possibility through theoretical verification, although I'd gladly accept whatever edit to my answer, from someone with credentials appreciably better than my own, might lend credibility to the possibility of such verification.  The motivation of those adding mass to their star would, of course, be the eventual appearance of a down-scaled replica of their observable region.)

Comment: My "update" is an attempted meld of the world as perceived by biological creatures (like ourselves) with the results of the recent experiment described in the last of my comments on Physics Teacher's answer to the OP's question. To visual learners (who may all be biological), I'd say those results leave Poplawski's torsion-based inflation, set in the interiors of black holes, preferable to inflation based on scalar fields that don't rotate and never have a value of zero.